# Passport authentication ReferenceError: user is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to make an authentication system for my website.

But when trying to log in with **any** combination I am receiving the following error in the website:

```
ReferenceError: user is not defined
user is not defined

ReferenceError: user is not defined
    at Strategy._verify (/home/jarno/0__projects/nodejs/EasyOrders/routes/users.js:76:36)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/home/jarno/0__projects/nodejs/EasyOrders/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:90:12)
    at attempt (/home/jarno/0__projects/nodejs/EasyOrders/node_modules...
```

In the console:

```
POST /users/login 500 204.677 ms - 3063
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/jarno/0__projects/nodejs/EasyOrders/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)...
```

My code:

**Users.js**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
  },

  function(email, password, done) {
    User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
      }
    });
    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
      }
    });
  }
));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect:'/users/login', failureFlash: true}),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

module.exports = router;
```

**User.js** model:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
}

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback) {
  var query = {email: email};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
      }
    });
    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
      }
    });
```

You are trying to use user.password when it's not already defined.
You need to nest the User.comparePassword function inside User.getUserByEmail or properly resolve it using promises.

Answer (score 0):

Well the prompted message show that the user is not defined. It's the message error throwns in users.js .I think, You forgot  to mention the name of your passport strategie that you have defined. Your code in users.js should be like this :

```html
 passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({.......})
```